# How to detect when a key is no longer pressed?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, keyboard

I'm doing a C # application for Windows that will detect when a key is no longer pressed.
So how can I do this?

PS: I know how to detect when a key is pressed.

Thanks for your atention.

Comment: So you want to know when the key up event is raised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You handle the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event to detect when the key goes down, and then handle the [`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) event to detect when it goes back up.